# Update a property in document in an Express route (Mongoose, MongoDB, Express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've successfully set up the registration and login functionality using Express, MongoDB and Mongoose.

I would like to log when the user last visited the site once the user's credential is accepted in a `lastConnection` property of the user document,

I tried but "lastConnection" is null (see the line below where I add a comment)

```
router.post("/login", async function(req, res) {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateLoginInput(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      errors.email = "Email already exists";
    }

    console.log("user ", user); <-- returns an object with the datas of user

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
      if (isMatch) {
        const payload = {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name
        };

        user.lastConnection = new Date(); <-- doesn't work

        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          keys.secretOrKey,
          {
            expiresIn: 7200
          },
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: "Bearer " + token
            });
          }
        );
      } else {
        errors.password = "Password is not correct";
        // return res
        //   .status(400)
        //   .json({ passwordincorrect: "Password incorrect" });
      }
    });
  });

  return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors)
  };
});
```

Any ideas? I think I have to do an update but I don't know where to put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `user.lastConnection = new Date();` with

```js
user.update({ lastConnection: new Date() })
   .then( updatedUser => {
        console.log(updatedUser)
        // put jwt.sign code here
    })
```

Comment: I’ll try tomorrow because I’m about to sleep, I keep you aware of the issue, thanks

Comment: sounds good. to clarify, we are console logging the updatedUser object to determine whether or not the user was in fact updated, you can also use MongoDB Compass or other methods to verify

Comment: My pleasure, best of luck!